# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy creando un carrito de compras en mi proyecto Laravel 5.7, estoy usando un @if(count) para contar los registros que tiene mi tabla,tambien estoy usando variables de sesion que en este caso la estoy llamando cart, el problema viene cuando al ejecutar la funcion trash que en teoria deberia eliminar mi variable de sesion eliminando todos mis registros me sale el error, cuando elimino los registros uno por uno el mensaje sale correctamente pero al presionar el boto vaciar carrito me sale el error.

Anexo el codigo de la vista, la ruta y funcion del controlador

```
<div>
<div class="page-header">
  <center>  <h1><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Comprar!</h1></center>
</div>

 <div class="container">
    @if(count($a1))
    <p>
    <a href="{{ route('cart-trash')}}" class="btn btn-danger">
    Vaciar Carrito <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </a>
    </p>
 
     <table class="table table-striped hover table-bordered">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Imagen</th>
                 <th>Producto</th>
                 <th>Precio</th>
                 <th>Cantidad</th>
                 <th>Subtotal</th>
                 <th>Quitar</th>
                 <tbody>
                     @foreach($a1 as $a2)
                     <tr>
                  <td><img style="width:85px; height:85px;" src="{{ asset('img/'.$a2->imagen) }}"></td>
                  <td>{{$a2->nombre_producto}}</td>
                  <td>{{number_format ($a2->precio_producto)}}</td>
                  <td>{{$a2->quantity}}</td>
                  <td>{{number_format($a2->price * $a2->quantity,2)}}</td>
                  <td>
                      <a href="{{route('cart-delete',$a2->id_producto)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                  </td>
                     </tr>
                     @endforeach
                 </tbody>
             </tr>
         </thead>
     </table>
 </div>
 @else 
 <h3><span class="label label-warning">NO HAY PRODUCTOS EN EL CARRITO :(</span></h3>
 @endif
```

Mi ruta y mi Funcion del Controlador

```
public function trash()
    {
         \Session::forget('cart');
         return redirect('cart/show');
    }
```

Ruta

```
Route::get('cart/trash',[
    'as' => 'cart-trash',
    'uses' => 'CartController@trash'
   ]);
```

Comment: Y si en vez de quitar la variable de sesión, le asignas como valor un array vacío? Después de todo estás redirigiendo a `cart/show`.

Answer (score 0):

Debes estar eliminando completamente el contenido y la referencia de la variable (esta quedando en `null` en vez de un array vacio, por ello `count(null)` entrega un warning).

No queda claro si la variable `$a1` es la misma variable de sesion que almacena el la lista de productos del carro, pero si es asi, basta con cambiar

```
\Session::forget('cart');
```

por

```
\Session::set('cart', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

[count()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) es la función nativa de PHP para obtener el tamaño de un array (u objetos contables).

Si tratas de usarla con una variable que no sea de tipo array: null, string, number, etc., tendrás un error.

En tu caso, puedes crear *el carrito* como un array vació al cargar la tienda, y mantener siempre el array en sesión. Vaciarlo si es necesario, nunca eliminarlo. Por ejemplo:

*Crear / vaciar variable de sesión para el carrito:*

```
session('cart', []);
```

Otra opción que tienes es modificar tu condición en *Blade*, de:

```
@if(count($a1))
```

a:

```
@if($a1 && is_array($a1))
```

En este segundo caso preguntas primero si `$a1` tiene contenido (puede ser un array o no). Si es un array vacío no pasa la condición, lo mismo si tienes una variable sin contenido, por tanto no pintas el carrito. Si la variable tiene contenido seguidamente preguntas si es un array, función [is_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-array.php), pasa la validación solo en casi afirmativo.

*Nota: entiendo que en `$a1` tienes el contenido del carrito recuperado de la sesión.*